# Is it possible to make an X,Y,Z scatter plot in LaTex?

Tags: graphics, graphs, draw

I need to make a scatter plot with the following points: $(1,1,0), (-2,0,2)$, and $(2,1,1)$ and then I need to draw a plane through the three points. I don't really know much about creating graphs in LaTex so I am not sure where to even begin. Can someone please help me with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is all straightforward with tikz-3plot, for instance. (I am not claiming that this is necessarily the best choice. If you want to draw real 3D objects, use asymptote. However, this problem is simple enough to be attacked by tikz.) Unfortunately, you did not specify how large the plane is and, more importantly, what the view angles should be. To show that this matters, I show an animation in which I draw the points, a sort of "minimal" plane, and animate one angle.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\foreach \X in {0,10,...,350}
{\begin{tikzpicture}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{70}{\X}
\draw[clip] (-4,-4) rectangle (4,4);
\begin{scope}[tdplot_main_coords]
\path (1,1,0) coordinate (X1) (-2,0,2) coordinate (X2) (2,1,1) coordinate (X3);
\fill[gray!20] (X1) -- (X2) -- (X3) -- ($(X1)+(X3)-(X2)$) -- (X1);
\end{scope}
\foreach \X in {1,2,3}
{\shade[ball color=blue] (X\X) circle (2pt);}
\end{tikzpicture}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Of course, if you give more input, I will be happy to adjust this. Here is a version with axes.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\foreach \X in {0,10,...,350}
{\begin{tikzpicture}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{70}{\X}
\draw[clip] (-4,-4) rectangle (4,4);
\begin{scope}[tdplot_main_coords]
\draw [-latex] (0,0,0) -- (1,0,0) node[pos=1.5]{$x$};
\draw [-latex] (0,0,0) -- (0,1,0) node[pos=1.5]{$y$};
\draw [-latex] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,1) node[pos=1.5]{$z$};
\path (1,1,0) coordinate (X1) (-2,0,2) coordinate (X2) (2,1,1) coordinate (X3);
\fill[gray,opacity=0.2] (X1) -- (X2) -- (X3) -- ($(X1)+(X3)-(X2)$) -- (X1);
\end{scope}
\foreach \X in {1,2,3}
{\shade[ball color=blue] (X\X) circle (2pt);}
\end{tikzpicture}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**ADDENDUM**: One way of embedding this in an article.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,tikz-3dplot}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
% the following packages are not needed to draw the plane
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\section{A plane}

A plane in three dimensions can be defined by three points which do not sit on
one line. In \cref{fig:Plane} we depict a plane that is defined by the points
\begin{equation}
 P_1=(1,1,0)\;,\quad P_2=(-2,0,2) \quad\text{and}\quad P_3=(2,1,1)\;.
\end{equation}

\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
 \begin{tikzpicture}
  \tdplotsetmaincoords{70}{110}
  \draw[clip] (-4,-4) rectangle (4,4);
  \begin{scope}[tdplot_main_coords]
   \draw [-latex] (0,0,0) -- (1,0,0) node[pos=1.5]{$x$};
   \draw [-latex] (0,0,0) -- (0,1,0) node[pos=1.5]{$y$};
   \draw [-latex] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,1) node[pos=1.5]{$z$};
   \path (1,1,0) coordinate (X1) (-2,0,2) coordinate (X2) (2,1,1) coordinate (X3);
   \fill[gray,opacity=0.2] (X1) -- (X2) -- (X3) -- ($(X1)+(X3)-(X2)$) -- (X1);
  \end{scope}
  \foreach \X in {1,2,3}
  {\shade[ball color=blue] (X\X) circle (2pt);}
 \end{tikzpicture}
\caption{A plane in three dimensions.} 
\label{fig:Plane} 
\end{figure}

\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: the reason why I didn't specify is because I did not know exactly what I want. Would it be possible to add the visible X, Y, and Z axis to the graph?

Comment: Would I be able to use this if the document class was article instead of what you have here? How would I add this to an already existing article?

Comment: what is the benefit of putting it in the    figure environment? When I do that, it moves the graph to the top of the page instead of where I want it.

Comment: @MohammedShahid figures are floats. You can tell them where you want them to have by adding a placement option like in `\begin{figure}[h]`. There are at least three benefits: You can add a caption with `\caption{This is a plane.}`, say, you can add a label (after `\caption`) like `\label{fig:Plane}` and then refer to the figure "As illustrated in Figure~\ref{fig:Plane}" and you can generate a list of figures. BTW, if you submit your article to a journal, almost certainly you have to use this environment.

Comment: @MohammedShahid I just added a simple example in which a plane is in a figure of an article. (I just picked random view angles, I am sure you will find better ones, and loaded a few packages that make life easier here.)

Comment: thank you for that. That makes a lot of sense. I am doing this for an undergraduate Math homework assignment so I am not really that close to publishing anywhere, but I will add it as a a figure with a caption anyway. Thank you so much.

Comment: how would I edit this in order to sketch 2 lines on a 2-D graph instead of a full plane on a 3-D graph?

Comment: @MohammedShahid I guess you don't need tikz-3dplot then. But I'd kindly like to ask a separate question for this. The present question, and perhaps also the answer, might be useful for others. Asking questions is free of charge, and that way you will also hear other opinions and learn new possibilities. (Plus I will decouple in a few minutes. ;-)